# Can we add an immutable policy to an Azure Storage with premium performance?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The immutable blob storage policy option within the Access policy is visible only for standard performance settings. Is there a way to implement the same with premium performance for v2 storage

Answer (score 0):

That isn't true. I have a Premium V2 storage account and I'm able to set policies for immutable blob storage at the container level.

Go to: `Azure Portal > {your-storage-account} > {your-container} > Access Policies > + Add Policy`

[image: Storage Account Access Policy]